# Path with slashes instead of arrows?

Tags: finder

Before when I right clicked on a file > info > copy path it would ouput a path like

**Applications/⁩MAMP⁩**

Now it outputs the path with arrows like

**‎⁨⁨Applications⁩ ▸ ⁨MAMP**

How can I change it? Or is there an easy way to copy a file path without these arrows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than going via Get Info, you can get the path more directly…

Right click, then hold  <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd> , Copy *[xyz]* as Pathname

[image]

which pastes as 
`/Users/[me]/Documents/SE Reviews.rtf`

Comment: thank you, but wondering why it worked differently before (i changed computer and I think OS changed)

Comment: It changed at Mojave, I really don't know why; but this way is quicker anyway ;)